# Google Cast - Example CastRemoteDisplay-android not working?

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm desperately trying to make the following sample code running: 
https://github.com/googlecast/CastRemoteDisplay-android.

There are 2 ChromeCast devices up-and-running on my network (and working with other sample applications)

According to the setup instructions:

- I created a new app ID for a Remote Display Receiver, with the name "CastRemoteDisplay"
- I copied the resulting app ID into the string resource "app_id"

When I run the application, the button is not visible. The problem is clearly located on that statement:

> mMediaRouteSelector = new
>   MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
>   **.addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast(getString(R.string.app_id)))**
>   .build();

What am I missing?

Thanks for your feedback
Serge

Comment: Just forgot to mention: both devices are registered as Cast Receiver Devices in the Google Cast SDK Developer Console.

Answer (score 0):

Deducing from your explanation, I think you mistook "`app_name`" for "`app_id`". You see, they're entirely different values. Looking at the format alone from the [strings.xml of android cast sample](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/blob/master/res/values/strings.xml)

```
<string name="app_name">Cast Videos Sample</string>
<string name="app_id">4F8B3483</string>
```

You said you placed "`CastRemoteDisplay`" for `app_id` but looking at the format, "`app_id`" is a set of random alphanumeric characters. So your "`CastRemoteDisplay`" is for `app_name`. Now for the value of `app_id`, look for values in your Cast Dev Console which resembles this format "`4F8B3483`".

Hope that helps.